How to find value and direction of solana transaction like solscan
I'd like to know how i can get information on transfers on solana tokens in a format similar to that of solscan, i.e: signature, time, action , from, to, value of transaction
For a specific mint i get the signatures using the getSignaturesForAddress RPC Method however when parsing the transactions with the getTransaction RPC Method I am unsure how to extract the required information from the Json output. I tried subtracting pre token balances from post token balances however it doesn't seem to work.
Also how would it be possible to calculate the value/price of the swap? Given that raydium accepts other tokens as means of trade is it possible to put a price on these trades?
I'm sure it is a simple answer but help is appreciated
Thanks

You might want to check out Helius' parsed transaction API.
const response = await fetch('https://api.helius.xyz/v0/transactions', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({}),
});
const data = await response.json();

It's far richer than the default getTransaction method, if you don't want the hustle of going through the hassle of interpreting the instruction, post and pre balances.
[
  {
    "description": "Human readable interpretation of the transaction",
    "type": "UNKNOWN",
    "source": "FORM_FUNCTION",
    "fee": 5000,
    "feePayer": "8cRrU1NzNpjL3k2BwjW3VixAcX6VFc29KHr4KZg8cs2Y",
    "signature": "yy5BT9benHhx8fGCvhcAfTtLEHAtRJ3hRTzVL16bdrTCWm63t2vapfrZQZLJC3RcuagekaXjSs2zUGQvbcto8DK",
    "slot": 148277128,
    "timestamp": 1656442333,
    "nativeTransfers": [
      {
        "fromUserAccount": "text",
        "toUserAccount": "text"
      }
    ],
    "tokenTransfers": [
      {
        "fromUserAccount": "text",
        "toUserAccount": "text",
        "fromTokenAccount": "text",
        "toTokenAccount": "text",
        "tokenAmount": 0,
        "mint": "DsfCsbbPH77p6yeLS1i4ag9UA5gP9xWSvdCx72FJjLsx"
      }
    ],
    "accountData": [
      {
        "account": "text",
        "nativeBalanceChange": 0,
        "tokenBalanceChanges": [
          {
            "userAccount": "F54ZGuxyb2gA7vRjzWKLWEMQqCfJxDY1whtqtjdq4CJ",
            "tokenAccount": "2kvmbRybhrcptDnwyNv6oiFGFEnRVv7MvVyqsxkirgdn",
            "mint": "DUSTawucrTsGU8hcqRdHDCbuYhCPADMLM2VcCb8VnFnQ",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "text"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "transactionError": {
      "error": "text"
    },
    "instructions": [
      {
        "accounts": [
          "8uX6yiUuH4UjUb1gMGJAdkXorSuKshqsFGDCFShcK88B"
        ],
        "data": "kdL8HQJrbbvQRGXmoadaja1Qvs",
        "programId": "MEisE1HzehtrDpAAT8PnLHjpSSkRYakotTuJRPjTpo8",
        "innerInstructions": [
          {
            "accounts": [
              "text"
            ],
            "data": "text",
            "programId": "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "events": {
      "nft": {
        "description": "text",
        "type": "NFT_SALE",
        "source": "FORM_FUNCTION",
        "amount": 1000000,
        "fee": 5000,
        "feePayer": "8cRrU1NzNpjL3k2BwjW3VixAcX6VFc29KHr4KZg8cs2Y",
        "signature": "4jzQxVTaJ4Fe4Fct9y1aaT9hmVyEjpCqE2bL8JMnuLZbzHZwaL4kZZvNEZ6bEj6fGmiAdCPjmNQHCf8v994PAgDf",
        "slot": 148277128,
        "timestamp": 1656442333,
        "saleType": "AUCTION",
        "buyer": "text",
        "seller": "text",
        "staker": "text",
        "nfts": [
          {
            "mint": "DsfCsbbPH77p6yeLS1i4ag9UA5gP9xWSvdCx72FJjLsx",
            "tokenStandard": "NonFungible"
          }
        ]
      },
      "swap": {
        "nativeInput": {
          "account": "2uySTNgvGT2kwqpfgLiSgeBLR3wQyye1i1A2iQWoPiFr",
          "amount": "100000000"
        },
        "nativeOutput": {
          "account": "2uySTNgvGT2kwqpfgLiSgeBLR3wQyye1i1A2iQWoPiFr",
          "amount": "100000000"
        },
        "tokenInputs": [
          {
            "userAccount": "F54ZGuxyb2gA7vRjzWKLWEMQqCfJxDY1whtqtjdq4CJ",
            "tokenAccount": "2kvmbRybhrcptDnwyNv6oiFGFEnRVv7MvVyqsxkirgdn",
            "mint": "DUSTawucrTsGU8hcqRdHDCbuYhCPADMLM2VcCb8VnFnQ",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "text"
            }
          }
        ],
        "tokenOutputs": [
          {
            "userAccount": "F54ZGuxyb2gA7vRjzWKLWEMQqCfJxDY1whtqtjdq4CJ",
            "tokenAccount": "2kvmbRybhrcptDnwyNv6oiFGFEnRVv7MvVyqsxkirgdn",
            "mint": "DUSTawucrTsGU8hcqRdHDCbuYhCPADMLM2VcCb8VnFnQ",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "text"
            }
          }
        ],
        "tokenFees": [
          {
            "userAccount": "F54ZGuxyb2gA7vRjzWKLWEMQqCfJxDY1whtqtjdq4CJ",
            "tokenAccount": "2kvmbRybhrcptDnwyNv6oiFGFEnRVv7MvVyqsxkirgdn",
            "mint": "DUSTawucrTsGU8hcqRdHDCbuYhCPADMLM2VcCb8VnFnQ",
            "rawTokenAmount": {
              "tokenAmount": "text"
            }
          }
        ],
        "nativeFees": [
          {
            "account": "2uySTNgvGT2kwqpfgLiSgeBLR3wQyye1i1A2iQWoPiFr",
            "amount": "100000000"
          }
        ],
        "innerSwaps": [
          {
            "tokenInputs": [
              {
                "fromUserAccount": "text",
                "toUserAccount": "text",
                "fromTokenAccount": "text",
                "toTokenAccount": "text",
                "tokenAmount": 0,
                "mint": "DsfCsbbPH77p6yeLS1i4ag9UA5gP9xWSvdCx72FJjLsx"
              }
            ],
            "tokenOutputs": [
              {
                "fromUserAccount": "text",
                "toUserAccount": "text",
                "fromTokenAccount": "text",
                "toTokenAccount": "text",
                "tokenAmount": 0,
                "mint": "DsfCsbbPH77p6yeLS1i4ag9UA5gP9xWSvdCx72FJjLsx"
              }
            ],
            "tokenFees": [
              {
                "fromUserAccount": "text",
                "toUserAccount": "text",
                "fromTokenAccount": "text",
                "toTokenAccount": "text",
                "tokenAmount": 0,
                "mint": "DsfCsbbPH77p6yeLS1i4ag9UA5gP9xWSvdCx72FJjLsx"
              }
            ],
            "nativeFees": [
              {
                "fromUserAccount": "text",
                "toUserAccount": "text"
              }
            ],
            "programInfo": {
              "source": "ORCA",
              "account": "whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc",
              "programName": "ORCA_WHIRLPOOLS",
              "instructionName": "whirlpoolSwap"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]

